# Solve the following system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the following system of equations:
$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x^3(1-x)+y^3(1-y)=12xy+18\\
\left | 3x-2y+10 \right |+\left | 2x-3y \right |=10 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Comment: No source, no motivation, no effort beyond cut'n'paste --- not good for this website.

Comment: yeah same from me.show some effort ,show steps where you've stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps asking Mathematica([WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%20%281%20-%20x%29%20%2b%20y%5E3%20%281%20-%20y%29%20==%2012%20x%20y%20%2b%2018,%20%20%20Abs%5B3%20x%20-%202%20y%20%2b%2010%5D%20%2b%20Abs%5B2%20x%20-%203%20y%5D%20==%2010) gives the answer as well) to solve it:

```
Solve[{x^3 (1 - x) + y^3 (1 - y) == 12 x y + 18, 
       Abs[3 x - 2 y + 10] + Abs[2 x - 3 y] == 10}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

immediately gives:

$$\left\{\left\{x\to -\sqrt{3},y\to \sqrt{3}\right\}\right\}$$

And there is this nice plot of the two curves:

[image]

P.S. I will probably(if I find a reason to) add an analytic answer later.